# Syntax of sql to test result query

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, hql

i have some issue here with testing result of select query

```
String hql2="select sum(SousEval_Note)  from SousEvaluation sv, Categorie ctg WHERE   AND ctg.CATEGORIE_ID =2";
Query  q2 =session.createSQLQuery(hql2);
List sumResultList2 = q2.list();
System.out.println("SUM of SousEvaluation not: "+ sumResultList2 != null ? sumResultList2.get(0) : 0.0);
```

And i want to make this test :

```
if(((sumResultList2.get(0)).equals(0))){// i have problem here  in this line
    String hql="update Evaluation e SET e.Eval_NoteGlobal ="+sumResultList1.get(0)+" WHERE EVAL_ID ="+ideval+" ";

    Query q= session.createSQLQuery(hql);
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```

knowing i work with hibernate3 and struts2 for my webapp

Comment: "Some issue" is a very generic problem description. What is the actual, concrete, problem?

Comment: this expression is not `if(((sumResultList2.get(0)).equals(0))){` recognize

Comment: Your SQL (`hql2)` is not valid.  `WHERE` clause starts with `AND`.

Comment: Just i put exemple  sql hql2  is work finly i had tested but my problem is this syntax `if(((sumResultList2.get(0)).equals(0))){` is not recognize

Comment: do you get an exception in runtime?

Comment: I have solved my issue jast I have done `if(((sumResultList2.get(0)).equals(0.0))){`  cause i have double